# get ip and url from ngx_http_request_t in nginx module

Tags: c, module, nginx

I need to get client ip and uri he/she requested in ngnix by `ngx_http_request_t` struct in nginx module.

as you know nginx module write like following code

```
ngx_http_sql_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r){//Code Here}
```

how can I get ip and uri from `r`,how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the IP from:

```
&r->connection->addr_text
```

Where **addr_text** is **ngx_str_t**

Answer (score 0):

A `ngx_http_request_t` is a typedef for `ngx_http_request_s`. See http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/ngx_http.h#0016.

It looks as follows (from http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/ngx_http_request.h#0358):

```
0358 struct ngx_http_request_s {
0359     uint32_t                          signature;         /* "HTTP" */
0360 
0361     ngx_connection_t                 *connection;
0362 
0363     void                            **ctx;
0364     void                            **main_conf;
0365     void                            **srv_conf;
0366     void                            **loc_conf;
0367 
0368     ngx_http_event_handler_pt         read_event_handler;
0369     ngx_http_event_handler_pt         write_event_handler;
...
0394     ngx_str_t                         request_line;
0395     ngx_str_t                         uri;
0396     ngx_str_t                         args;
0397     ngx_str_t                         exten;
0398     ngx_str_t                         unparsed_uri;
...
};
```

`ngx_connection_t` is a `ngx_connection_s`, and you can find its definition at http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/core/ngx_connection.h#0117.

The `ngx_connection_t` has a `ngx_socket_t`. Once you have the socket, you can get the IP from `sin_addr.s_addr`.

The URI is available as just an nginx string.

Comment: What about getting the origin?